# Add form to branded share point site (office 365)

Tags: sharepoint, office365

How do I add a form (like below) in SharePoint (Office 365). I am posting from site.com to another_site.com. It is a branded site and I want the form in the master page.

I currently get this error: Your master page has one or more HTML  tags. For your master page to work, remove the tags (but you can leave the content in them).

```
    <form action="http://another_site/test" method="post">
       <div class="form-group">
          <div class="radio">
             <input type="radio" name="request" value="demo">Request
          </div>
          <input name="fullname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" required="required">                                                                                     
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
      </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would use a content editor webpart to incorporate the form, would that work? You then can embed the webpart into the masterpage.